# How do you create a MySQL View that uses the LAG() Function?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I am trying to create a VIEW utilizing the LAG() function

MySQL 8.0.30

### NOT WORKING:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW diff_view AS
    SELECT 
          pk_id_autonumber AS `pk_id_autonumber`,
          date_time AS `date_time`,
          p_last AS `p_last`
          p_last - LAG(p_last,1,) AS 'diff'
    FROM
         p_tbl
```

---

### THIS WORKS:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW diff_view AS
    SELECT 
          pk_id_autonumber AS `pk_id_autonumber`,
          date_time AS `date_time`,
          p_last AS `p_last`

    FROM
         p_tbl
```

---

Where should I be adding:

```
      p_last - LAG(p_last,1,) AS 'diff'
```

and what am I missing additionally?

Comment: and what happened?

Comment: you are missing a comma after ```AS `p_last` ```

Comment: *NOT WORKING* - due to syntax error. LAG() cannot be used without OVER clause.

Comment: and what's with the extra comma inside the LAG()? and you are missing the OVER window

Comment: Lag() always needs an ordering because tables do not have an intrinsic order of rows.  In your case it's probably p_last, so specify it like this: `lag(p_last) Over (Order By p_last)`.  Notice I took out the ,1, from inside the lag() - the default lag is one record.  In addition,  if you have other keys in this table you will probably need a Partition By clause to keep the different date lists separate.

Comment: Syntax Error(s) associated with:  p_last - LAG(p_last,1,) AS 'diff'

Comment: I modify statement to  p_last - LAG(p_last,1) OVER w AS 'diff' FROM p_tbl WINDOW w AS ORDER BY id;
and error remains.

Comment: This is my first time using stackoverflow.  I am blown away by the rapidity, helpfulness, and quality of the assistance.  Thank you to those assisting!

Comment: Do not imagine your own syntax, follow MySQL syntax.

Comment: also, it's a good idea to just do your select without a view first to test it; get it working and then make it a view.  (or not, IMO views almost never help anything except making queries harder to understand)